# How to search text string and select item in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a table attribute with complete roads name.
I have to search items by digiting a part of the road name and I need to colour all the items selected.

eg: ROAD NAME: / road 01 / road 02 / road 11 / road 12

I need to colour all items that contain "1" (so all the items except the second one).
I would like to set the string operator is this way:
ROAD NAME ILIKE ' * 1 * ' but it does not work

*edit* I work in advanced search in table attribute

Comment: Do you want to select them for extraction or an operation; or do you want to just colour them?

Comment: I only need to search some items on the project, so for my aim it is enough to colour them on the screen.

Comment: You can find the solution reading the comment below (use % instead of *)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if the attribute is called ROAD NAME, the query should be

```
"ROAD NAME" LIKE '%1%'
```

Comment: I have also tried this way but I think that the problem is on the second part of the query. This query works (ROAD NAME ILIKE 'road 01') while this query do not works (ROAD NAME ILIKE ' * 1 * '). It seems it do not recognize the char * as I need.

Comment: Don't use `ILIKE` use `LIKE`

Comment: @NathanW neither with LIKE. I understand that the difference between LIKE and ILIKE is only that ILIKE is not case sensitive

Comment: @Giulio Have you tried % instead of *?

Comment: @underdark That's it! Thanks, I hope it will help other users

Comment: great. i've updated the orginal answer

Comment: Well, darn it. I'm trying something similar and it's not working at all. I want to select a road named 'Los Llanitos' from an attribute table, and I've used  "FULLNAME" LIKE '%LLANITOS%' -- because in this layer, that is the attribute column which holds the names of the roads -- but nothing gets selected! And I've manually checked the attribute table to affirm that yes, the road is in the table and I have used the correct name. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? TKX.

Comment: @Catlike as far as I remember the comparison tools are case-sensitive

Comment: @Catlike, if you want the search to be insensitive to case use 'ILIKE' instead of 'LIKE' as per the comment above.