# How to search and move to feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

After solving [how to search text string](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65160/how-to-search-text-string-and-select-item-in-qgis/65241#65241) I need to move to the selected feature.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Alexandre Neto solution works! You can move just with (Ctrl + J)

Comment: How can we write this one programmatically using python programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different options to "move" to the selected feature(s).

You can Zoom to Selected features by:

- Click the "Zoom to Selection" button in "Map navigation" Toolbar
- Using the menus View > "Zoom to Selection" (Ctrl + J)
- Click the "Zoom Map to Selected rows" in the layer table of attributes

[image]

You can Pan to Selected features by:

- Click the "Pan Map to Selection" button in "Map navigation" Toolbar
- View > "Pan Map to Selection" (Ctrl + J)
- Click the "Zoom Map to Selected rows" in the layer table of attributes

[image]

Both this options will zoom or pan to the entire set of selected features of the active layer. If you want to zoom\pan to each of the selected features one at a time, you can use the [Item Browser Plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/itembrowser/).

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Enable editing on your layer.  Select your feature. In the editing toolbar click on the 'move feature(s)' tool (four arrows icon).  This will move the whole feature.  If you want to edit the shape of the feature then use the Node Tool.